# Dynamical inheritance TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

JavaScript permit dynamical inheritance. I was wondering if TypeScript take it into account. The following code might illustrate the problem.

```
// inheritance.js
function fn1() {
  this.a = "fn1";
}

function fn2() {
  // ...
}

let f1 = new fn1(); // "instance" of fn1
let f2 = new fn2(); // "instance" of fn2

// inheritance
f2.__proto__ = f1;

// f2.a inherits from f1
console.log(f2.a); // output: "fn1"
```

As you can see we add an object f1, which is an instance of fn1, in the prototype chain of f2.
My question is therefore the following: can we reproduce this behave in TypeScript by using classes?
How would I change the following code to have the expected output?

```
// inheritance.ts
class class1 {
  public a: string = "class1";
}

class class2 extends class1 {
  // ...
}

let c1 = new class1();
let c2 = new class2();

console.log(c1.a); // output: "class1"

// this line would not work
c2.__proto__ = c1;

// change value c1.a
c1.a = "dynamical inheritance test";

console.log(c2.a); // should print value of c1.a (i.e "dynamical inheritance test")
```

Comment: That's not inheritance, that's violence.

Comment: A deep thank Teemu for your constructive and perceptive comment

Comment: You're wellcome! The comment is actually very usefull, see [all the red](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)  around the subject.

Comment: Ok you are right, thanks for the cautionnery advice about the use of .__proto__. I used here .__proto__ to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Note that the .js  file obtained, by transpilling the solution given by baao, does not contain any .__proto__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is like an intersection mixing. There's a simple example found at the [typescript docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). To do what you want, you, you can basically just assign the mixing's resulting class to the to inheriting class, then copy all properties of the class you want to be the extending to the result:

```
function extendDynamic<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
    let result = <T & U>{};
    (<any>result) = (<any>first);
    for (let it in second) {
        if (second.hasOwnProperty(it)) {
            (<any>result)[it] = (<any>second[it]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

class Class1 {
    public a: string;
    constructor(n: string) {
        this.a = n;
    }
}

class Class2 {
    b: string = 'bbb';
}

const a = new Class1("bar");
const b = extendDynamic(a, new Class2());
a.a = 'foo';
console.log(b.a, b.b); // foo, bbb
```

Comment: Thank you baao, that is exactly what I was looking for :)